# ACF Repeater Field not displaying in second post

Tags: php, advanced-custom-fields

I work with a site that was built on WordPress using mostly ACF. I'm currently trying to add a new function by adding a ‘rates and seasons’ custom post type. Basically there are hundreds of properties that all share the same date ranges and seasons, but with different prices.

So what I set up is a custom post type with a repeater field to enter the date ranges and seasons so when it comes time to update the dates, we only have to update the 'rates' posts rather than 120+ individual properties. I've done something similar for other aspects of the site (terms and conditions, neighborhood etc) Unfortunately… I'm having trouble getting this one to work. When the custom post type is chosen, none of the data in the repeater field displays. I’ve read through a forums, and the ACF guides, and tried a few fixes, but I’ve come to the point where I really need a new set of eyes.

Here is the code for the custom post type:

```
register_field_group(array (
'id' => 'acf_rates',
'title' => 'Rates',
'fields' => array (array (
    'key' => 'field_5a8fdfe319dec',
    'label' => 'Rates per Date Ranges',
    'name' => 'rates_per_date_template',
    'type' => 'repeater',
    'sub_fields' => array (
    array ( 'key' => 'field_5a8fe01d19ded',
        'label' => 'Starting Date',
        'name' => 'rates_start',
        'type' => 'date_picker',
        'instructions' => '',
        'required' => 0,
        'conditional_logic' => 0,
        'wrapper' => array('width' => '','class' => '','id' => '',),
        'display_format' => 'm/d/Y',
        'return_format' => 'Ymd',
        'first_day' => 0,
    ),
    array ( 'key'   => 'field_5a8fe06b19dee',
        'label' => 'Ending Date',
        'name'  => 'rates_end',
        'type' => 'date_picker',
        'instructions' => '',
        'required' => 0,
        'conditional_logic' => 0,
        'wrapper' => array('width' => '','class' => '','id' => '',),
        'display_format' => 'm/d/Y',
        'return_format' => 'Ymd',
        'first_day' => 0,
    ),
    array(  'key' => 'field_5b47bf4e86700',
        'label' => 'rates seasons',
        'name' => 'rates_seasons',
        'type' => 'select',
        'instructions' => '',
        'required' => 0,
        'conditional_logic' => 0,
        'wrapper' => array('width' => '33','class' => '','id' => '',),
        'choices' => array('Low' => 'Low',
                   'Low and Mid' => 'Low and Mid',
                'Mid' => 'Mid',
                'High' => 'High',
                'Holiday' => 'Holiday', ),
        'default_value' => array(   ),
        'allow_null' => 0,
        'multiple' => 0,
        'ui' => 0,
        'ajax' => 0,
        'return_format' => 'value',
        'placeholder' => '',    ),
    ),
    'row_min' => '',
    'row_limit' => '',
    'layout' => 'table',
    'button_label' => 'Add Date Range',
),),
```

Here is the code to call up the custom post type in the property:

```
array(  'key' => 'field_5b47cd1a17dfc',
    'label' => 'Pick Rates Template',
    'name' => 'rates_template',
    'type' => 'relationship',
    'instructions' => '',
    'required' => 0,
    'conditional_logic' => array(
    array(  array(  'field' => 'field_5b47cccb17dfb',
            'operator' => '==',
            'value' => 'Yes',
    ),  ),  ),
    'wrapper'   => array(   'width' => '', 'class' => '', 'id' => '', ),
    'post_type' => array(   0 => 'rates',   ),
    'taxonomy'  => array(),
    'filters'   => array(   0 => 'search',
                    1 => 'post_type',       ),
    'elements'  => '',
    'min'       => '',
    'max'       => '',
    'return_format' => 'id',
),
```

Now here's where the problems come up. The post registers that I've selected a custom post type in the relationship field. But none of the data in the rows shows up. Here's the last piece of the code:

```
$low      = get_field('base_low_season_price');
$mid      = get_field('base_mid_season_price');
$high     = get_field('base_high_season_price');
$holiday  = get_field('base_holiday_season_price');
$temp_rates = get_field('rates_template')

if ($rates || $rental_rates || $rental_rands) : 
echo '<a name="Rates"></a><br />';
  if ($temp_rates) :
    echo'<h2 class="blue">Rental Rates & Seasons
             <a href="#Top" class="totop">Back to Top</a></h2>
<table class="rates" width="75%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" cellcolor="#b7d8f9">
<tbody><tr><th>Starting</th><th>Ending</th><th>Season</th><th>Rate</th></tr>';
if(get_field('rental_rates')) {$rates = implode(get_field('rates'));}
        $rates_rows = get_field('rates_per_date_template',$rates);
if( have_rows('rates_per_date_template',$temp_rates) ):
    while( have_rows('rates_per_date_template',$temp_rates) ) : the_row();
        $rates_rows     = get_row('rates_per_date_template');
            $rates_start    = get_sub_field('rates_start');
            $rates_end  = get_sub_field('rates_end');
            $rates_seasons  = get_sub_field('rates_seasons');
    foreach ($temp_rates as $temp_rate) :
        $currentdate = date("Ymd",mktime(0,0,0,date("m"),date("d")-1,date("Y")));
        $starting = $rates_start;
    $sy = substr($starting, 0, 4);
    $sm = substr($starting, 4, 2);
    $sd = substr($starting, 6, 2);
    $tstime = strtotime("{$sd}-{$sm}-{$sy}");

    $ending = $rates_end;
    $ey = substr($ending, 0, 4);
    $em = substr($ending, 4, 2);
    $ed = substr($ending, 6, 2);
    $tetime = strtotime("{$ed}-{$em}-{$ey}");

    if ($ending >= $currentdate)                            
    {echo   '<tr>   <td>'.date('F jS, Y',$tstime).'</td>
            <td>'.date('F jS, Y',$tetime).'</td>
            <td>'.$rates_seasons.'</td>';
        switch ($rates_seasons) {
            case "Low": 
            echo '<td>'.$low.'</td>';
            break;
            case "Low and Mid": 
            echo '<td>'.$low.'</td>';
            break;
            case "Mid": 
            echo '<td>'.$mid.'</td>';
            break;
            case "High":    
            echo '<td>'.$high.'</td>';
            break;
            case "Holiday": 
            echo '<td>'.$holiday.'</td>';
            break;
        }
        echo '</tr>';
        }
        endforeach;
        endwhile;
    endif;
    elseif ($rental_rates) :
echo '<h2 class="blue">Rental Rates & Seasons<a href="#Top" class="totop">Back to Top</a></h2>
<table class="rates" width="75%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" cellcolor="#b7d8f9"><tbody>
<tr><th>Starting</th><th>Ending</th><th>Rate</th></tr>';
$currentdate = date("Ymd",mktime(0,0,0,date("m"),date("d")-1,date("Y")));
foreach ($rental_rates as $rental_rate) :
    $starting = $rental_rate['starting'];
    $sy = substr($starting, 0, 4);
        $sm = substr($starting, 4, 2);
        $sd = substr($starting, 6, 2);
    $stime = strtotime("{$sd}-{$sm}-{$sy}");

        $ending = $rental_rate['ending'];
        $ey = substr($ending, 0, 4);
        $em = substr($ending, 4, 2);
        $ed = substr($ending, 6, 2);
    $etime = strtotime("{$ed}-{$em}-{$ey}");
    if ($ending >= $currentdate) 
    {   echo    '<tr>   <td>'.date('F jS, Y',$stime).'</td>
                    <td>'.date('F jS, Y',$etime).'</td>
                <td>'.$rental_rate['price'].'</td></tr>';
    }
    endforeach;
    endif;
echo '</tbody></table>';
endif;
```

The code to render the dates works when used by the dates entered on the individual property (it makes all dates before today disappear on the front end). Also, the switch statement works, I tested it with the native date ranges from the individual properties and it displays nicely. But as soon as I try to call up the data from the repeater on my custom post type the code stops working and all I get are the Table Header Row labels and nothing else. If anyone could look at this for me and let me know what I'm doing wrong I'd really appreciate it!!!!

Comment: You haven't shown how you're getting the post data. Is it a full WP_Query loop, or are you using get_posts() or some other method? Anyway, `get_field()` will only work in a loop. To use it outside of a loop you must pass in the post ID as the second attribute - eg, `get_field('base_low_season_price', $post_ID)`

Comment: According to ACF documentation the 'if (have_rows('') while(have_rows) is supposed to act like a loop. But I'll change to the $post_id (fingers crossed)

Comment: It's working! Thank you! I was confused since I had the relationship post set to return Id's, but that doesn't mean that I didn't have to actually call up the individual post id! thank you so much for the tip @PeterHvD ! I'll post the final code below so hopefully this can help someone else!

Answer (score 0):

Alright, thanks to @PeterHvD 's help, I've got the code worked out! Here is the new section below!

```
if ($temp_rates):
    echo'<h2 class="blue">Rental Rates & Seasons<a href="#Top" class="totop">Back to Top</a></h2>
        <table class="rates" width="75%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" cellcolor="#b7d8f9"><tbody>
        <tr><th>Starting</th><th>Ending</th><th>Season</th><th>Rate</th></tr>';
        $posts = $temp_rates;
        foreach( $posts as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post );
        if (have_rows('rates_per_date_template',$post->ID) ):
            while( have_rows('rates_per_date_template',$post->ID) ): the_row();
                    $rates_start    = get_sub_field('rates_start');
                    $rates_end      = get_sub_field('rates_end');
                    $rates_seasons  = get_sub_field('rates_seasons');
                    $currentdate = date("Ymd",mktime(0,0,0,date("m"),date("d")-1,date("Y")));
                        $starting = $rates_start;
                        $sy = substr($starting, 0, 4);
                        $sm = substr($starting, 4, 2);
                        $sd = substr($starting, 6, 2);
                        $tstime = strtotime("{$sd}-{$sm}-{$sy}");
                        $ending = $rates_end;
                        $ey = substr($ending, 0, 4);
                        $em = substr($ending, 4, 2);
                        $ed = substr($ending, 6, 2);
                        $tetime = strtotime("{$ed}-{$em}-{$ey}");
                        if ($ending >= $currentdate)                            
                        {   echo '<tr>  <td>'.date('F jS, Y',$tstime).'</td>
                                        <td>'.date('F jS, Y',$tetime).'</td>
                                        <td>'.$rates_seasons.'</td>';
                            switch ($rates_seasons) {
                                case "Low":     
                                    echo '<td>'.$low.'</td>';
                                    break;
                                case "Low and Mid": 
                                    echo '<td>'.$low.'</td>';
                                    break;
                                case "Mid": 
                                    echo '<td>'.$mid.'</td>';
                                    break;
                                case "High":    
                                    echo '<td>'.$high.'</td>';
                                    break;
                                case "Holiday": 
                                    echo '<td>'.$holiday.'</td>';
                                    break;
                            }
                            echo '</tr>';
                        }
            endwhile;
            endif;
        endforeach;
        wp_reset_query();
```

So I had to do the full mark up for the relationship field, including reseting $posts as the custom post type, then calling the post id for the selected custom post type (rates) and *then* call up the repeater field via the 'have_rows, the_rows' loop. I had skipped the middle step and had wrongly assumed that by calling up the relationship field, and setting it to return id's that $temp_rates would work in place of the $post->ID. Its working just right now! Thanks again Peter!